# How to change object(in same lib but different path) at same time in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

My project folder like this:

- --*main.js*
- --lib
- ------libA
- ----------*a.js*
- ------libB
- ----------*b.js*
- ----------lib
- --------------libA
- ------------------*a.js*

In *main.js*:

```
var obja = require('./lib/libA/a');
require('./lib/libB/b');
```

In *b.js*:

```
var obja = require('./lib/libA/a');
```

In *a.js*:

```
module.exports = {};
```

Then if I changed **obja** in *b.js*, **obja** in *main.js* did not change.

My question is how to change two **obja** at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: If a.js like util.js use *obja = require('a');*, then issue is resolved. But how to change module.paths globle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different `a.js` files — one in `lib/libA`, and the other in `lib/libB/lib/libA`. Those are two different modules, and each of them has its own `exports` object. If you want to reference the same `a` module, you need to change your `b.js` file to:

```
var obja = require('../libA/a');
```

This way, both `main.js` and `b.js` will refer to the same module (the one in `lib/libA/a.js`).

Comment: When I develop libB, there is no libA out side. If I can put libA in a globle modules.path, then I can var obja = require('a') instead. Just like require('util'). But how to set modules.path globle?

Comment: You can put `a.js` in the `node_modules` folder in your application root: see [Loading from node_modules folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) That way you will be able to import it simply as `require('a')`.

Comment: It is a solution. But I'm confused that: whether it is wrong to change object in NodeJS lib. We never change object in common NodeJS lib such as jasmine-node, jshint, uglify-js......

Comment: I believe it is okay, as long as you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, if you get rid of the obja variable and just reference libA.a you can change it in both places that way - assuming you are in the same process / cluster

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is helpful. But I have to export libA.a. Is there more elegant way?

Comment: @coordinate this is the most elegant way

Comment: If libB isn't a lib developed by me, I can not change it to reference libA.a. So I'm confused that: whether it is wrong to change object in NodeJS lib. We never change object in common NodeJS lib such as jasmine-node, jshint, uglify-js......